# Modify a pandas dataframe so that two or more cells will be merged and centered when opened in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I've seen some solutions but couldn't apply them after trying many times.
The code I used is based on the [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_merge1.html).
In the following example the intention is to merge cells with the value 1:

```
df = p.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
writer = p.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.merge_range('B2:B3', '1')
worksheet.close()
```

`worksheet.close()` resulted in the error:

> AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'close'

which I couldn't find a solution for.
Is that the correct approach? Is something missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you intend to overwrite the cells B2 and B3 updated with the values 4 and 5 respectively, with a merged cell having the value 1? If so then right approach, but you cant close a sheet, as mentioned in the answers you close the writer, by either method

Answer (score 3):

Change to:

```py
writer.close()
```

Because it is the writer you have to close and not the sheet.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the code using with statement so that you don't have to worry about closing

```
df = p.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
with p.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    worksheet.merge_range('B2:B3', '1')
```